# Profiling Django views line-by-line

Tags: python, django, profiling, view, httprequest

I have a Django application with views which I hope to profile with [line_profiler](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/) or similar line-by-line profiling methods. I have successfully tested line_profiler on other python scripts, but have not figured out the best way to do so on Django views. All of the views I have created are initiated by MATLAB url requests and are thus difficult to debug. What I need is some way of wrapping the views such that when a request is made line_profiler will create a statistics file for later viewing (right now, the only way I have figured out how to use line_profiler is through explicit calls to a script with kernprof.py in the terminal - perhaps simulating an http request at this step would work, but none of my attempts in this vein have succeeded.). If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

1. [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/) which provides a bunch of debug information, including a profiler.
2. [django-devserver](https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver) which is a drop-in replacement for django's `runserver` and has support for `line_profiler`

Just have to add the module since it's not enabled by default

```
DEVSERVER_MODULES = (
    'devserver.modules.sql.SQLRealTimeModule',
    'devserver.modules.sql.SQLSummaryModule',
    'devserver.modules.profile.ProfileSummaryModule',

    # Modules not enabled by default
    'devserver.modules.ajax.AjaxDumpModule',
    'devserver.modules.profile.MemoryUseModule',
    'devserver.modules.cache.CacheSummaryModule',
    'devserver.modules.profile.LineProfilerModule',
)
```

Comment: This solution works, although I ended up writing a view that wraps other views with the line_profiler.